# How to add ellipsis for an array of certain length?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario in which I have a array with objects I need to display that array separated by commas. After certain elements of array I need to add ellipsis.

Here is my code:

```
<div><b>Eye color:</b><span ng-repeat="eyeAry in eyeClrTxtAry | limitTo:10"> {{eyeAry}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
     </span>
    <span ng-if="eyeClrTxtAry.length >5">...</span>
 </div>
```

The above code is used for adding ellipsis. My problem is when length exceeds '5', the ellipsis is added to every element after length '5'. My requirement is to hide the elements which are greater than '5' by adding ellipsis (...).

Answer (score 0):

channge limit to 6 and add track by $index

```
<div><b>Eye color:</b><span ng-repeat="eyeAry in eyeClrTxtAry track by $index | limitTo:6"> {{eyeAry}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
 </span>
<span ng-if="$index >4">...</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind to output the entire collection you could stick to a CSS solution.
Check the [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property.

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```